# Function declaration returns 'error: parameter 'array' may not appear in this context'

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a function that I'm trying to have use one of its parameters for another one of its parameters. Declaration:

```
template<num_type T> void sort(vector<T> &array, bool ltog = true, VecRange range = VecRange(0, array.size() - 1));
```

When I try to do this, the compiler throws an error: `error: parameter 'array' may not appear in this context`. My question is can I do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not refer to parameters in parameter declarations if they are evaluated. You can refer them only in an unevaluated context as for example used in the `sizeof` operator.

In your function declaration

```
template<num_type T> void sort(vector<T> &array, bool ltog = true, VecRange range = VecRange(0, array.size() - 1));
```

the parameter `array` is used in the evaluated expression `VecRange(0, array.size() - 1)`.

An example when such a reference tp a parameter in a parameter declaration list is valid

```
template <typename T>
void f( const T &x, size_t y = sizeof( x ) );
```

Comment: Could you modify your answer to help me understand it?

Comment: What do you not understand, specifically?

Comment: What is an 'unevaluated context'?

Comment: @farnz For example an expression in the sizeof operator is not evaluated. In your example the expression array.size() is evaluated to get its value. And the value can be obtained only at run-time.